# Upload a Photo to Facebook with REST API and Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, mime

It's much harder than you'd think:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Photos.upload

The tricky part is how to create the MIME multi-part message in Rails, which Facebook requires. I'm also using a Ruby Facebook API gem (mini_fb) which signs my other requests, and in addition to having no idea how to set up the MIME multi-part, even if I did I'm not sure how to add in the required signature values with the gem.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [Facebooker](http://github.com/mmangino/facebooker)?  Or even if you have some reason not to you can reverse engineer the [upload photo method](http://facebooker.rubyforge.org/classes/Facebooker/User.html#M000456).